# PECS For generics in Non Collections

Tags: java, generics, collections, bounded-wildcard

Joshua Bloch came up with the PECS, which says the rule when to use `? extends T` and `? super T`. If you think about PECS in terms of Collections framework, then it is very straightforward. If you add values to the data structure, use `? super T`. If you read from the data structure, use `? extends T`.
for instance:

```
public class Collections {  
    public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {  
        for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++)   
            dest.set(i, src.get(i));   
    }   
}
```

If I check the signature of

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

I see Comparator uses `? super`, so it should be a consumer. Looking at the code, comparator c is only used to produce stuff because it is asked the logic of comparing.

On one hand, I understand why it is a super because as a developer I want to use comparators of class `T` and also comparators of super class `T` because objects of `T` is also of type super classes of `T`. But when I try to think in terms of PECS, I fail to understand.

Does PECS only hold for Collections framework? If not, Can someone explain to me what does comparator consume in `Collections.sort`?

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of this answer, let's take `Comparator` as the main, guiding example.

If you think carefully about it, you'll see that `Comparator` actually **receives** two arguments of type `T` and returns the result of their comparison (represented by an `int`). In other words, it *consumes* two instances of type `T` and *produces* an `int` value. So, as by the PECS rule, it is a *consumer* of `T`, hence the use of `? super T`.

More generally, you should consider *producer* and *consumer* from the point of view of the main type with regard to the types of each one of its generic parameters. If some `Comparator` type *consumes* objects of type `T`, the PECS rule states that users of such `Comparator<T>` could use it to compare objects whose type is a subtype of `T`.

As a specific example, if you happen to already have the logic to compare two generic `Number` instances (no matter what their concrete type actually is), you could use it i.e. to compare `Double` instances, because doubles are numbers, after all.

Consider the following comparator:

```
Comparator<Number> c = Comparator.comparingInt(Number::intValue);
```

Here, the comparator `c` compares `Number` instances (*any* number) by taking into consideration only their integral part.

If you have the following list of `Double` instances:

```
List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(2.2, 2.1, 7.3, 0.2, 8.4, 9.5, 3.8);
```

And the following `sort` method:

```
static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<T> c) {
    list.sort(c);
}
```

(Note the absence of the wildcard `? super T` in the `Comparator` argument).

Then, if you want to sort the `List<Double> doubles` list, the signature of the above `sort` method would require you to pass a concrete `Comparator<Double>`. But what if you wanted to use your previously defined `c` comparator to sort the `List<Double> doubles`?

As that comparator's type is `Comparator<Number>`, and as the `doubles` list's type is `List<Double>`, the following code would produce a compilation error:

```
sort(doubles, c);
```

Fortunately, as `Comparator` is a *consumer* of the type of the elements it compares, you can change the signature of the `sort` method to:

```
static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    list.sort(c);
}
```

And now, this code would compile:

```
sort(doubles, c);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the super clean explanation. I want to give a further example with Iterator<T>. If I design a method which calls T next() then I should design my signature with ? extends because Iterator now produces T. 

It can be generalized as if the generic class in the method consumes T( like in the case of comparator)  it should be super, if it returns a reference to T (like in the case of iterator) then it should be extends.

Comment: @FatihArslan Yes, that's correct. For example, if you have a method that receives an `Iterator<Number>` and you attempt to pass an `Iterator<Integer>`, it won't compile. But if you change the method, so that it now receives an `Iterator<? extends Number>`, you will be able to to pass the `Iterator<Integer>` without problems. And wildcards can be mixed, too. For example, the `Stream.map` method receives a `Function<? super T, ? extends R>`.